# Windows.Storage function returning wrong file count

Tags: c#, uwp

I am using Windows.Storage GetFilesAsync function to retrieve file information, but am finding that the file count is often incorrect (compared to OS properties). Strangely sometimes the number is smaller and other times larger than the OS count!?

I've created a mini project to replicate the issue. On folders with very small file count, they do match, but with larger counts (i.e. 500+) the count is often way off.

To replicate create a Universal Windows blank app, then copy this to MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
x:Class="TestFileCount.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:TestFileCount"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <Button Name="btnSelect" Content="Select Folder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="195" Margin="254,412,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="805" Click="btnSelect_Click"/>
    <TextBlock Name="txtFolder" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="92" Margin="185,212,0,0" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1156"/>
    <TextBlock Name="txtResult"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="163" Margin="96,701,0,0" Text="" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1210"/>

</Grid>
```

Finally copy this to MainPage.xaml.cs and run the app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.FileProperties;
using Windows.Storage.Search;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;


namespace TestFileCount
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
      public MainPage()
      {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void btnSelect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        const string SizeProperty = "System.Size";
        const string DateModProperty = "System.DateModified";

        var folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker
        {
            SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Desktop
        };

        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");


        StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();

        //cancelled
        if (folder == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        txtResult.Text = "Processing...";
        txtFolder.Text = folder.Path;
        btnSelect.IsEnabled = false;

        // Set up file settings
        List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
        List<string> propertyNames = new List<string>
        {
            SizeProperty,
            DateModProperty
        };

        // Create query options
        QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, fileTypeFilter)
        {
            FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep,
            IndexerOption = IndexerOption.UseIndexerWhenAvailable
        };
        queryOptions.SetPropertyPrefetch(PropertyPrefetchOptions.BasicProperties, propertyNames);

        StorageFileQueryResult query = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);

        //get files
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> fileList = await query.GetFilesAsync();

        txtResult.Text = fileList.Count.ToString();
        btnSelect.IsEnabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because it includes subfolders? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.search.folderdepth

Comment: Try FolderDepth.Shallow option

Comment: I do need files in subfolders so shallow is not an option.

Comment: Do you need to treat folders as file?

Comment: No, I am just interested in files. I am worried that this function is missing some files. Or is returning some multiple times. The file count is sometimes less and sometimes more than the OS.

Comment: Are these files hidden? Provide reproducible folder on which it does not work well. Maybe you have file links which refers to the same file. Your code is correct, seems like your problem is related to files.

Comment: Have you tried the following method to return count? await query.GetItemCountAsync() Does it show the same number of files?

Comment: See my updated answer, hope it'll help.

Answer (score 1):

It seem to be a known issue and it does not work because of OrderByName. Delete OrderByName.

```
QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions(){...};
```

It's mentioned [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/049572e1-5248-426b-950a-f886dbfaa784/uwpc-storagefoldergetfilesasync-is-not-working?forum=wpdevelop) that it does not work outside of the library folder contrary to the documentation which states that it works everywhere.
Even though I tested it on my PC and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try that. Currently, I cannot replicate the higher than OS count!?

Comment: I wonder if it wasn't an issue with WIndows indexing service?

Comment: @under according to the documentation OrderByName is intended to provide flat list of files with subfolders ordered by name. Then I don't understand what is the purpose of FolderDepth. Seems like they have different parameters which do the same. And no wonder that this code is buggy.